# Count the number of days from a specific date and data range

Tags: r, date, count

I would like to count the number of times that `value` appears `>20` from a specific date defined by the number 1 of column (`ncol = 1`) for the previous `5` days. For example, the date `1997.05.25` how many times the value appears `>20` to `1997.05.21`.

Here are the variables:

```
value <- c(37,19.75,19.5,14.5,24.75,25,25.5,19.75,19.75,14.25,21.25,21.75,17.5,16.25,14.5,
               14.5,14.75,9.5,11.75,15.25,14.25,16.5,13.5,18.25,13.5,11.25,10.75,12,8.5,
               9.75,14.75)
    Date <- c("1997-05-01","1997-05-02","1997-05-03","1997-05-04","1997-05-05",
              "1997-05-06","1997-05-07","1997-05-08","1997-05-09","1997-05-10",
              "1997-05-11","1997-05-12","1997-05-13","1997-05-14","1997-05-15",
              "1997-05-16","1997-05-17","1997-05-18","1997-05-19","1997-05-20",
              "1997-05-21","1997-05-22","1997-05-23","1997-05-24","1997-05-25",
              "1997-05-26","1997-05-27","1997-05-28","1997-05-29","1997-05-30",
              "1997-05-31")
    ncol <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`

    data <- data.frame(value, Date, ncol)

    library(data.table)

    setDT(data)[, ncol := ifelse(Date %in% c("1997-05-05","1997-05-11","1997-05-14",
                                             "1997-05-18","1997-05-25"), ncol+1, 0) ]
```

how to do that best? Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my expected result:

```
 1. value Date  ncol newcol
 2. 37.00 1997-05-05 1 2
 3. 19.75 1997-05-11 1 2
 4. 19.50 1997-05-14 1 2
 5. 14.50 1997-05-18 1 0
 6. 24.75 1997-05-25 1 0
```

Comment: It might be good to add your expected output since, judging by the answers, it is ambiguous

Comment: Thanks a lo @docendo discimus. Put the result I would like to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)

data %>%
    filter(between(Date, "1997-05-01", "1997-05-21"),
          value > 20) %>%
    nrow()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use `Reduce` and `shift`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(value, Date)

DT[, ncol := Reduce(`+`, shift(value > 20, 1:5, fill = 0))]
```

What this does: it counts, for each row of DT, how many time the `value`-column in the previous 5 rows was greater than 20 and writes that into column `ncol`.

---

If you wanted to change this 5-row "window" from the previous 5 days to include the current day + the previous 4 rows, you would change the code to:

```
DT[, ncol := Reduce(`+`, shift(value > 20, 0:4, fill = 0))]
```

Comment: Nice! But I guess the question wants to sum the number of cases where `value > 20` in the five previous days (not rows). To my mind, this looks like a problem of summarizing a `data.table` by a moving interval

Comment: @RafaelPereira, perhaps you're right. I'm not sure though and that's why I asked the OP to provide their desired output in the question.

Comment: Great! That was it. Thanks. I wanted to count including the current day. However, is not necessary all lines, would be only the days that has the column with the number 1 (specific date). One question, how can I select only the lines that want to create a new table with date and newcol?

Comment: @Gustavo, I don't see any 1s in your sample data so I can't help you there.